# chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation alternative in Selenium RC

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-rc

I have a simple need. I just want to click the "Cancel" button of the Confirmation Popup from Python Selenium RC Client without using chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation. Is there any Javascript alternate to do this? 

Just like selenium webdriver has alert.dismiss, can I achieve the same functionality in Selenium without chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation? The reason why I don't want to use chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation is because it needs to be called before the popup is present.


In short, I just want to achieve something like this:

```
# Using Python Selenium RC Client
# This works for clicking Ok....
click('foo') # Clicks on button 'foo' which brings up a confirmation popup
get_confirmation() # Clicks 'Ok' on the popup

# This works for clicking Cancel....
choose_cancel_on_next_confirmation() # Click on cancel for next popup
click('foo') # Clicks on button 'foo' which brings up a confirmation popup
get_confirmation() # Clicks 'Cancel' on the popup

# This is what I want....
click('foo') # Clicks on button 'foo' which brings up a confirmation popup
run_script('some script to click cancel')  # Clicks 'Cancel' on the popup
```

It will be great if anyone out there knows how to achieve it using javascript?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

No.  Selenium RC goes to a lot of trouble to capture the confirmation popups and you have to use its `choose_cancel_on_next_confirmation()`, `get_confirmation()` API to work with them.